# Google Analyics 4 Click Data

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, google-analytics-4

I have just started using the new Google Analytics 4 and find so many features from the previous versions of Google Analytics are missing. One of the main features that I can see in GA4 that looks promising is the automatically included event tracking.

The issue I am having though is when I then try to drill down into the 'click' data to view the link URLs that have been clicked there is only the 'events in the last 30 minutes' and no way of viewing the data from the last week for example.

Am I just completely missing something? Does the data have to be accessed in a different way (data studio perhaps)? or is it only possible to view the previous 30 minutes of data before its gone forever?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the new reports (not only the real time):

[image]

Check here for some details about new reporting and navigation in Google Analytics 4: https://www.kristaseiden.com/new-reporting-navigation-in-appweb/